# Friendly Url on Root Web

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation

We have a SP2013 site. **We want to allow creating friendly URLs for pages under the root site, e.g. - `contoso.com/my-page` linked to `contoso.com/pages/my-page.aspx`.**

Is it possible?

Not sure if it makes any difference but our site also has variations for 3 languages: `contoso.com/english`, `contoso.com/french`, `contoso.com/spanish`. The FURLs work fine under those variation subsites, e.g. - `contoso.com/english/my-page` correctly redirects to `contoso.com/english/pages/my-page.aspx`.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

To clarify - I know very little about SharePoint :D

From the comments below I now understand and can confirm that the english variation is now my root site, because when I go to `contoso.com` it redirects me to `contoso.com/english`.

With this setup would it still be possible to generate friendly urls pointing to whatever other page on any of the variations subsites. **I want to support these scenarios**:

- `contoso.com/news` redirect to `contoso.com/english/pages/news.aspx`
- `contoso.com/summer2013sale` redirect to `contoso.com/english/sales/pages/summer2013sale.aspx`
- `contoso.com/si` > `contoso.com/spanish/pages/si.aspx`

Basically I want something like [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) - more of a redirect functionality, but only for my own site `contoso.com`.

If this is not possible with the managed navigation, maybe there is another approach that I can take. Any pointers in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: Not quite understanding your setup, what type of pages would you need to have directly on the root instead of being part of the variations?

Comment: AFAIK, if you have variations enabled.. The SOURCE variation becomes your root-site ? isn't it ? Like if you access `contoso.com`, it will redirect to `contoso.com/english` (considering English is Source Variation)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri exactly my point :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren yeah, sorry for repeating it in different words :D

Comment: Any clarification is good clarifaction :) @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: @RobertLindgren and ArsalanAdamKhatri thank you for the replies and apologies for the slow response. I've added additional info above.

Comment: I think the best solution is the rewrite Module for the iis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do that.
Thank you to ASP.NET 4 and Managed Navigation this is very easy to do on SharePoint 2013.

Please refer to these links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194310.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311.aspx

Note:
**The cross-site publishing feature is available only in SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise.**

If you using a site with a Publish Template you have to do

1. Enable the Managed Metadata Navigation on the Site Settings > Navigation page

[image]

2. Define the Managed Metadata term set that will be used for navigation

[image]

On those links on top you can find a better walkthrough with all the details

Comment: This answer needs more details, it is overly-dependant on the two links. You should try to outline the basic steps in your answer :)

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio, thank you. I will try this tomorrow (end of the day here) and will accept it as answer then.

Comment: Please include the relevant content of the linked articles in your answer to protect against broken links.

Comment: Broken links ??? :| BTW I'm going to update the answer

Comment: Certainly. See: "Provide context for links - A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." from http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer (like how I did that?) There's nothing more frustrating than finding an answer containing dead links.